# Access 2013 vba docmd.OutputTo and TransferSpreadsheet syntax error

Tags: vba, export-to-excel, ms-access-2013

I believe I have a simple question, but it is completely boggling my mind at the moment.  I can't get either of the codes to not immediately give me a syntax error.

```
Private Sub btnManualExportInvoicing_Click()
Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Invoicing"

If Len(Dir(Filepath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir Filepath
End If

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet (acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _ 
"tblInvoicing", Filepath & "\Invoicing info & Format(date, "yyyy-mm-dd")&".xlsx" ,,)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet (1, 9, "tblInvoicing", Filepath & "\Invoicing info 
& Format(date, "yyyy-mm-dd")&".xlsx" ,,)

DoCmd.OutputTo (0, "tblInvoicing", acFormatXLSX, Filepath & "\Invoice Info" 
& , False,)


End Sub
```

All of these Do.cmd types give me a syntax error (highlighted red).  What am I missing?

Comment: I seem to have solved the issue by adding the Reference Library Microsoft Office (my version) 15.0 Object Library.  Seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

VBA requires various syntax rules especially with whitepsace and line breaks and compiler will raise errors immediately when you leave a problematic line. Such rules applicable to your situation include:

- line breaks within functions must be done with underscore
- space must precede and follow between objects and operators like `&`
- string literals must open and close with double quotes
- standalone function calls do not require parentheses such as`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet()` unless it is assigned to a variable `set obj = DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet()`

Therefore, consider the following adjustments:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tblInvoicing", _
          Filepath & "\Invoicing info" & Format(date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet 1, 9, "tblInvoicing", _ 
          Filepath & "\Invoicing info" & Format(date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

DoCmd.OutputTo 0, "tblInvoicing", acFormatXLSX, _
          Filepath & "\Invoice Info" & Format(date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx", False
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the quotes and the export type (to match the file extension) and remove the parenthesis:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml,"tblInvoicing", _
    Filepath & "\Invoicing info " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
```